# Hat diese Struktur einen Namen?

Tags: subjunctive

Ich habe schon mehrfach solche Sätze gelesen:

„Es sei dem Leser sogar verziehen, *sollte* er noch nie etwas von der Kalmückien *gehört haben*“

oder

„Sie *sollten* die Informationen weitgehend gut *verstanden haben*“

Man sieht, dass durch das Wort „sollte“ Konjunktiv 2 verwendet wird, aber die Struktur mit zusätzlichem Verb in Perfekt und dann haben/sein in Infinitiv kann ich in meinem Grammatikalischen Buch nicht finden.

Das ähnlichste zu diesen Strukturen, das ich gefunden habe ist die subjektive Bedeutung der Modalverben. Die aber bildet man mit „soll“ und nicht mit „sollte“.

Zum Beispiel:

„Trump Jr. soll gefährdetes Riesenschaf gejagt haben.“

Hat die Struktur in den oberen Beispielen einen Namen, den ich *verpasst haben könnte*? —> gleiches Problem

Comment: Warum sollte das einen eigenen Namen haben? Modalverben werden nunmal üblicherweise mit dem Infinitiv anderer Verben verwendet, und das andere Verb im Perfekt + Modalverb im Konjunktiv macht es jetzt nicht so außergewöhnlich, dass das einen eigenen Namen verdient hätte.

Comment: Diese drei Beispiele sind drei semantisch verschiedene Konstruktionen: "sollte er..." == für den Fall, dass...; "Sie sollten..." == so wäre es normalerweise; "soll gejagt haben" == hat angeblich gejagt. Schon deshalb ist keine einheitliche Bezeichnung angebracht.

Comment: _Kalmückien_ hat keinen Artikel, man würde also sagen _Ich habe noch nie etwas von Kalmückien gehört._ Wenn man von der _Republik Kalmückien_ sprechen würde, wäre der Artikel korrekt: _von der Republik Kalmückien_. Auch, wenn das Land _Kalmückei_ heißen würde, hätte es feminines Genus und würde einen Artikel tragen. Wenn die Bewohner des Landes gemeint sein sollten, müsste es heißen _er hat noch nie etwas von den Kalmücken gehört_ - natürlich alles passend zu der vom Satz verlangten Struktur, also _sollte er noch nie etwas von Kalmückien / von der Republik K. / von den Kalmücken gehört haben._

Comment: Muss man immer Infinitiv Perfekt benutzen, wenn man die Vergangenheit in dem Nebensatz ausdrucken möchte? Könnten die Sätze auch mit Infinitiv Präteritum statt Infinitiv Perfekt gebildet werden?  Beispiele: „Sie sollten die Informationen weitgehend gut verstanden“, oder „Hat die Struktur einen Namen, den ich verpassten könnte, oder „.....sollte er noch nie etwas von der Kalmückien hörten.“ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Kurzantwort**: Es handelt sich in allen drei Fällen um das Modalverb *sollen*, kombiniert mit einem Infinitiv Perfekt. Die Bedeutung von *sollen* ist dabei jeweils eine andere.

Das erste Beispiel ist ein **Konditionalsatz**. Im Deutschen kann Konditionalität in einem Nebensatz außer durch Konjunktionen (*wenn, falls, sofern*) mit Verb-Letzstellung auch durch einen Nebensatz ohne Konjunktion, dafür mit Kopfstellung des konjugierten Verbs, bezeichnet werden. Beispiel:

- Hätte ich das Geld, würde ich das Haus kaufen, anstatt es zu mieten.

Der Beispielssatz kann demnach so umformuliert werden:

> Es sei dem Leser sogar verziehen, wenn er noch nie etwas von Kalmückien gehört haben sollte.

Die Verbform *sollte* ist richtig als **Konjunktiv 2** bezeichnet, in diesem Fall nicht mit einem einfachen Infinitiv, sondern mit dem **Infinitiv Perfekt** von *hören*. *Sollte* trägt hier allein die Bedeutung *Konditionalität* als einer Form von *Möglichkeit* bzw. genauer *Eventualität*, welche, wenn sie real wird, das im Hauptsatz Genannte wahr bzw. wirksam werden lässt. Darüber hinaus kennzeichnet *sollte* einen vergleichsweise geringen Grad an Wahrscheinlichkeit, der sich in zugespitzter Weise folgendermaßen umschreiben ließe:

> Auch wenn einzelne Leser noch nie etwas von Kalmückien
>   gehört haben sollten, es sei ihnen jedenfalls verziehen, oder:
>
> In dem vermutlich höchst seltenen Fall, dass jemand noch nie
>   von Kalmückien gehört hätte, sei ihm verziehen.

Eine solche, etwas gewundene Denk- und Formulierungsweise erkläre ich mir so, dass der Autor/Sprecher einerseits die Erwartung äußern möchte, dass man Kalmückien wenigstens dem Namen nach kennen sollte, dass er jedoch andererseits niemanden "vorführen" will, auf den das nicht zutrifft. Da ich selbst von diesem Land noch nie und allenfalls von deren Bewohnern namentlich gehört habe, nehme ich mir die Freiheit, den Satz für Ironie zu halten.

In dem zweiten Beispiel (*Sie sollten die Informationen weitgehend gut verstanden haben*) kann eine analoge Verbform mit *sollten* als Konjunktiv 2 vorliegen. Der Satz ist allerdings in mehrfacher Hinsicht unklar, z.B. bin ich nicht sicher, ob sich das *weitgehend* auf *gut* oder auf *verstanden* bezieht, und das *Sie* kann das höfliche Anredepronomen *Sie* sein oder eine 3. Person Plural. Meine **Paraphrasen für mögliche Bedeutungen** wären:

> Sie (= die Zuhörer) müssten die Informationen eigentlich verstanden haben (es wurde ihnen ja alles ganz langsam und ausführlich erklärt).

Die Verbform wäre hier wieder der *Konjunktiv 2 von sollen mit Infinitiv Perfekt*. *Sollte* hat hier eine **subjektive Bedeutung**, denn auch die Konjunktivformen der Modalverben treten in subjektiver Bedeutung auf, hier ist es die einer **Vermutung**. *Sollte* für Vermutungen ist seltener als *müsste* und eher gehobene Standardsprache.

> (Bevor Sie sich selbst an die Reparatur heranwagen,) sollten Sie die Informationen (aus der Reparaturanleitung) gut verstanden haben.

Hier hat der *Konjunktiv 2 von sollte* die **subjektive Bedeutung** einer **Empfehlung**.

> (Der Abteilungsleiter erwartete / verlangte / sagte,) dass die Mitarbeiter die Informationen erst gut verstanden haben sollten, (bevor sie sich an die Umsetzung / Anwendung machten)

Hier kann es sich um das Präteritum oder wieder um den Konjunktiv 2 von *sollen* in einer **indirekten Rede** handeln. Eine indirekte Rede kann im Indikativ oder im Konjunktiv ausgeführt werden. Das Modalverb *sollen* wird oft dazu herangezogen, um auszudrücken, dass eine andere Person als der Sprecher und der Angesprochene erwartet, dass das im Infinitiv Genannte getan wird oder dass es bereits erledigt worden ist. So werden etwa Aufforderungen und Imperative über eine Mittelsperson mit *sollen* weitergegeben: *Sagen Sie dem Müller, er soll mich anrufen* oder *Schicken Sie mir mal den Müller.* Später der Beauftragte zu Müller: *Du sollst den Chef anrufen* / *Der Chef hat gesagt, du sollst ihn anrufen* bzw. *Du sollst zum Chef (kommen).*

Das dritte Beispiel (*Trump Jr. soll gefährdetes Riesenschaf gejagt haben*) wäre zu paraphrasieren als

> Die Leute sagen, dass / Es heißt, dass Trump Jr. ein gefährdetes R. gejagt hat / Nach den Aussagen einiger Zeugen hat Trump Jr. ...

Hier handelt es sich um die spezielle Form einer **distanzierenden Redewiedergabe**, mit der der Sprecher offen lässt, ob die Information wahr ist bzw. ob sie zutrifft. Es ist die typische Form der **Weitergabe von Hörensagen-Informationen**. Anderes Beispiel dafür:

- Er soll schon zweimal geschieden sein.

Comment: Danke fuer die auswendige Erklaerung. Muss man immer Infinitiv Perfekt benutzen, wenn man die Vergangenheit in dem Nebensatz ausdrucken möchte? Könnten die Sätze auch mit Infinitiv Präteritum statt Infinitiv Perfekt gebildet werden? Beispiele: „Sie sollten die Informationen weitgehend gut verstanden“, oder „Hat die Struktur einen Namen, den ich verpassten könnte, oder „.....sollte er noch nie etwas von der Kalmückien hörten.“ ?

Comment: @Gasper: Ein "Infinitiv Präteritum" existiert im Deutschen nicht, "verstanden" als Präteritum ist kein Infinitiv, sondern die erste oder dritte Person Plural im Präteritum von _verstehen_ und kann nur mit den Personalpronomen _wir_ oder _sie_ oder _Sie_ oder mit entsprechenden Subjekten verwendet werden (_mein Bruder und ich, die Leute, meine Geschwister, die Schüler ..._). "Ich verpassten" geht nicht, es müsste heißen "ich verpasst**e** den Bus". Modalverben als Modalverben (es gibt sie auch als Vollverben: _Ich kann das nicht!_) werden immer mit einem Infinitiv verbunden, ...

Comment: ... und da haben wir nur den einfachen Infinitiv 'Präsens' (_verstehen_) und den Infinitiv Perfekt (_verstanden haben_), diese beiden auch im Vorgangspassiv (_verstanden werden + verstanden worden sein_) und im 'Zustandspassiv' (_verstanden sein + verstanden gewesen sein_), und das Ganze dann alles noch einmal mit '_zu_' jeweils vor dem letzten Verb der Gruppe. Das heißt: Genau diese 7 Gruppen mit verstehen können mit einem Modalverb kombiniert werden, andere nicht, und bei '_nicht brauchen_' gibt es standardsprachlich die 7 Gruppen mit '_zu_', umgangssprachlich auch ohne _zu_.

Comment: Danke, jetzt verstehe ich es.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Vorzeitigkeit](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Vorzeitigkeit) heißt es, was der Teil *gehört haben* ausdrückt.
2. Die Formen von *sollen* haben in deinen Sätzen verschiedene Funktionen. Gehört das auch zu deiner Frage?